# Change Origin and rotate the frame of a mobile robot

Tags: modeling, transform-orientation

Apologies for a basic question posting. I don't have any experience with blender so its hard to search for solution with relevant keywords.

I have a robot model which actually is translated and rotated both. I have a few questions:

1. How can I make the body of the robot parent?
2. How to place the robot to origin(at the moment in air) and set its  heading in +ive x-axis, left +ive y-axis and z upwards when the robot is on flat surface.
3. Is there any way I can declare wheels as rotatable joints(Also may be how can I test it in blender)?

[image: Current position of the robot]

Comment: If you just started with blender, i highly suggest use newer version at least 2.8x or higher ... also would be better to attach blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: in general 1- parenting - select child than parent and press Ctrl+P / 2- rotation -if it is a one object go to edit mode (Tab key) and rotate and position model as needed / 3- too complex and more ways to do it - search for car rig

Answer (score 0):

select the body, then shift+s, cursor to selected, shift+a, empty-axis, select axis-empty, ctrl+i, then select axis-empty again, right mouse button, parent, object.  This parents to the body position where the axis is and all items are parented to the axis, but are moveable individually.  Move the axis for scale, rotation of all, or just the individual parts.

save a new file doing this to not lose work changed from.  Then add bones BEFORE all this, to selected areas using car rigging methods (search for appropriate online).  You rotate the bones added to the wheels and so forth, that you also parent to the RIG-axis-empty created.

to position all at the world origin, after you have made an axis parent, select the axis, then shift+s, cursor to world origin, then shift+s, selection to cursor.